# Right Click on a cell to copy the content of it

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a table created with QTableWidget. I want to copy the cell's content (data) with right click. I've searched the web but haven't found anything that works for the right click event. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement your own TableWidget class and override mousePressEvent() method:

```
class MyTableWidget : public QTableWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTableWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QTableWidget(parent)
    {}

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override {

        QTableWidget::mousePressEvent(event);

        if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton) {

            if(currentItem() == nullptr) {
                return;
            }

            QClipboard *clipboard = QGuiApplication::clipboard();
            clipboard->setText(currentItem()->text());
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: works like a charm! thanks. **sorry about late answer